# Wifi not working on new Ubuntu install on HP Stream 11

Tags: networking, wireless, hp, realtek-wireless

I recently purchased an HP Stream 11 (HP 11-y020wm) and installed Ubuntu on it, but I'm having trouble getting the wifi card to work. Here's the results of the wireless info script I found on the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108) and I did run the updates before trying it, as described in the post.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xH6vJmWHrH/

Oddly, when I got to wifi settings, it says that no wifi adapter is detected, but the bluetooth settings display normally when I thought they both used the same wireless networking card. It even allows me to pair devices, but after the initial pairing, it won't let me transfer files or connect headphones.

I'm currently using a Wifi dongle to access the internet, but would prefer to not have to use it since my device only has two USB ports.

EDIT: Result of `sudo modprobe r8822be` is `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8822be': Required key not available`

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8822be` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Okay, I ran it and edited the question.

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules TL; DR: Turn off secure boot, detach the dongle and you should be all set.

Comment: @chili555 Thank you so much, that worked! Is there any negative effects to having secure boot turned off?

Comment: Real world, I doubt there is any downside. Here is some very interesting reading: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/6kw648/linux_uefi_vs_legacy_ide_prosconssecurity/

Comment: @chili555 I'm not sure I completely understand that discussion, but it does make me think more about computer security. However, this comment section is probably not the place to discuss it. Thanks, again. This was really helpful.